# What is the appropriate tag to use for "database"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just asked a question [What columns are needed to list the database, schema and table a record comes from?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323074/what-columns-are-needed-to-list-the-database-schema-and-table-a-record-comes-fr) which asks about which 'database' a row comes from in a cross database/schema question and couldn't use [database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) as a tag.

What is the appropriate term for that?

Comment: You should tag your post firstly with which database *system* and version you're using. By the context of the code, I'm assuming it's PostgreSQL. That's always important, as the answer to most questions almost always depends on that information.

Answer (score 4):

Everything on this site is about "database", so adding that as a tag is pointless.

Comment: That's why the tag is blacklisted on the main site. It cannot be created.